# Beautiful Soup Get a Certain Paragraph

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a certain paragraph of text from a website, but my current methodology is not working.
I want the paragraph at the bottom. Thank you for your help, and I apologize for being a novice. I tried reading the docs but could not decipher much.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "https://pwcs.edu/"

r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

container = soup.find("div",attrs={'class': 'alertWrapper'})
paragraph = container.find("p")
```

When I print paragraph.getText() I get a bunch of blank space but no errors.

The html is :

```
    <div id="page">
<div id="em-alerts" role="alert">
   <div class="alertWrapper">
      <div class="container">
         <span class="icon dom-bg">
            <em class="fa fa-bell">
               <!---->
            </em>
         </span>
         <span id="alert">ALERT</span>
         <p>All PWCS will open two hours late on Thursday, February 8, due to icy road conditions in certain areas. SACC will open two hours late. Parents always have the option to keep children home if they have safety concerns.
         </p>
         <p></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want the paragraph at the bottom. Thank you for your help, and I apologize for being a novice. I tried reading the docs but could not decipher much.

Answer (score 2):

First you can get as close as you can to the paragraphs:

```
container = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'container'})
```

Then you look for all the `<p>` tags in the container and join them.

```
\n'.join([x.text for x in container.find_all('p') if x.text != ""])
```

This will put all the paragraphs together, linked by a newline between each paragraph *if they're not blank*.

**Output:**

> 'All PWCS will open two hours late on Thursday, February 8, due to icy
>   road conditions in certain areas. SACC will open two hours late.
>   Parents always have the option to keep children home if they have
>   safety concerns.\n         '

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

container = soup.find("div",attrs={'class': 'alertWrapper'})

paragraph = container.find("p")
```

In you above code you will be getting only first "p" tag. **container.find("p")** only gives you first "p" tag.

And the first tag you are getting is empty one.
You can check page source of that website.

But actually container has multiple "p" tags in it.

What you need to do is:

```
for p in container.find_all("p"):
    print p.text
```

Following is the Html content in **alertWrapper** class present on your website.

```
<div class="alertWrapper">
    <div class="container"><span class="icon dom-bg"><em class="fa fa-bell"><!-- --></em></span>

        <!--First "p" tag which is empty-->

        <p>               
        </p>
        <table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="" style="border: 3px solid rgb(0, 176, 240);">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class=""
                    style="margin: 2px; padding: 2px; border-image-source: none; border-image-slice: initial; border-image-width: initial; border-image-outset: initial; border-image-repeat: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                    <ul>


                        <!--Second "p" tag which you want-->

                        <p style="text-align: left; margin-left: 120px;"><strong><span
                                style='font-size: medium; letter-spacing: normal; font-family: "Times New Roman"; color: rgb(0, 112, 192);'>The PWCS Parent Divisionwide surveys, sent on January 9, were unexpectedly delayed at the US Post Office distribution center. The deadline for the parent survey, both paper and online, has been extended to Friday, February 9, 2018. </span></strong>
                        </p>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you right click and check the page source, the text you want is not available. The HTML you've provided and the page source doesn't match.

```
<div class="alertWrapper">
  <div class="container"><span class="icon dom-bg"><em class="fa fa-bell"><!----></em></span><p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<table style="border: 3px solid rgb(0, 176, 240);" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="">
    <tbody>
```

This is happening because the content you want is generated dynamically by JavaScript. You won't be able to scrape that using `requests` module.

You'll have to use other tools like [**Selenium**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: So I must used Selenium&#39;s live browser window? I dislike that it opens a new chrome window as this code is being used for a bot. Would it be possible to use Selenium without opening an actual window? Could i also build the soup object in a differenr way such that it will work?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with a headless browser like PhantomJS. Or even with Chromedriver you can use `--headless` as an argument.

Comment: `chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless'); driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)` You can do this.

Comment: `Could i also build the soup object in a differenr way such that it will work?`: BeautifulSoup is simply an HTML parser. Its object won't modify or change anything. The content you're getting with `requests` is the original page source without modification by JS.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there are multiple divs on that page with class "container". Therefore you could use `find_all()` method instead of `find()`. For example, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r  = requests.get("https://pwcs.edu/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

n = 0
for container in soup.find_all("div",attrs={'class': 'container'}):
    n += 1
    print('==',n,'==')
    for paragraph in container.find_all("p"):
        print(paragraph)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `.next_sibling`:

```
for span in soup.find_all("span",attrs={'id': 'alert'}):
    if span.next_sibling:
        print('ALERT',span.next_sibling)
```

Comment: with my current code I receive a blank paragraph element. Is this because the actual website collapses the p into <p>... </p>?